Three-dimensional isometries, confused about fixed elements
For a 4x4 matrix A representing an affine direct isometry in 3D, that takes points in homogeneous coordinates, I realize that the fixed elements are generally found by solving the eigenvalue problem. As I understand it, fixed points would represent the eigenvectors $$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ w \end {bmatrix}$$ where the element $w \neq 0$ and the corresponding eigenvalue is $1$. For the eigenvectors where $w=0$ and the eigenvalue is $1$, I understood this as the direction given by a fixed line? But what does it mean when an eigenvalue is $-1$ and has a corresponding eigenvector where $w=0$ ? What if there are two such eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs, what is the geometric interpretation of that? And how would you determine if a plane is fixed under the transformation?
I thought that maybe the multiplicity $2$ of the eigenvalue $-1$ meant that the corresponding eigenvectors generate a plane, but not how to interpret this geometrically. I thought maybe it meant a reflection, but is that even possible when $A$ is a direct isometry? I assumed it represented a rotation.

I have edited the post and clarified some details.
